# jPlayer: not loading jPlayer.swf on Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, firebug, jplayer, fallback

I built the website http://www.ordinarypeopleofficial.com using WordPress and the theme "Gleam" from the suite *Elegant Themes*. This theme is very complex. It heavily uses JavaScript. It has a 700 code lines long file called *custom.js*, which manages the whole website using AJAX.

For this reason I couldn't include the JavaScript code to load the jPlayer into the PHP script, but I needed to put it into a separate JavaScript file and call this file from *custom.js*.

In *custom.js* I added the following lines, which include my file named *chiama-player.js* into the `<head>` tag:

```
var html_doc = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
js.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
js.setAttribute('src', "/wp-content/themes/Gleam/chiama-player.js");
html_doc.appendChild(js);
```

The file named *chiama-player.js* contains the code to instantiate the jPlayer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if(window.location.href=="http://www.ordinarypeopleofficial.com/#!/le-canzoni/" || window.location.href=="http://www.ordinarypeopleofficial.com/le-canzoni/"){
    $("#jp_container_1").css( { 'display': 'block' } );
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( {
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "http://www.ordinarypeopleofficial.com/wp-content/themes/Gleam/shakeit.m4a",
            });
        },
        swfPath: "http://www.ordinarypeopleofficial.com/wp-content/themes/Gleam/jplayer",
        supplied: "m4a"
    });
}
else{
    $("#jp_container_1").css( { 'display': 'none' } );
}
});
```

THE PROBLEM:
Everything works GREAT on the browsers, which support M4A.

The problem comes with Firefox. Firefox does not support M4A, so it needs the Flash fallback to work. When I try to load the page on Firefox, I see that the `swfPath` is correctly recognized (in fact if I alter the path and I type some random text, I see a 404 in the *Net* panel).

The problem is that the request `GET Jplayer.swf` never gets a result and keeps loading for hours without getting the file.

Comment: If you have found the solution, please put in an an **answer**. This is important so that the question is no longer recorded as **unanswered**!

Comment: 2) i copied the content of the file jquery.jplayer.min.js and pasted it all (i know, it's horrible but it works). LOL.. good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into the file *custom.js*, at the end of the function `et_init_scripts()` I did the following steps:

1. I removed the lines I wrote, so I don't call my file *chiama-player.js* anymore
2. I copied the content of the file *jquery.jplayer.min.js* and pasted it all. (I know, it's horrible, but it works.)
3. Right after these lines I copied the content of *chiama-player.js* (which creates the jPlayer).